# Do I need a flight ticket or a flight reservation for my UK visit visa application

Tags: visas, uk, airlines, applications, proof-of-onward-travel

Am compiling documents for my visa application and I read that I need to present go and return flight tickets to prove that I will return at the end of my visit. Then a while ago I got to know that I can just get a flight reservation with out buying the flight tickets because the visa application can be refused and you have already bought the tickets. 
So l request to know which of the two , having a flight ticket or flight reservation is more compelling to the visa officer and more convenient me because I would buy a flight ticket and my application is refused

Answer (score 10):

No. UKVI guidance specifically states that travel arrangements should not be made prior to receiving your visa.

Section 4 of [the UK government's Supporting Documents Guide for Visitors](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk) lists flight and hotel bookings as documents that are NOT required to be submitted with the application:

> **4.**
>
> **Documents you should not send unless specifically requested.**
>
> This section provides guidance on the types of documents that are not required to consider your application.
>
> ...
>
> - hotel bookings
> - flight bookings
>
> ...

If you present documents that are not required you may give the ECO the impression that you don’t understand the rules or didn’t bother to read them.