# can I reapply UK tourist visa on priority basis after getting refusal

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, applications

I got refusal on my application for Tourist visa of UK, can I reapply on priority or super priority basis because I have booked my tickets and hotels.

Comment: You always can reapply, but success is very unlikely without changes in your circumstance

Comment: Why was it refused? You’ll need to address their concern(s) to have a chance of success.

Answer (score 7):

There’s nothing in the Immigration Rules to prevent you from reapplying on a priority/super priority basis after a refusal. However:

- flight and hotel bookings are NOT required to be submitted with the application, doing so won’t help you get a visa [Do I need a flight ticket or a flight reservation for my UK visit visa application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130843/do-i-need-a-flight-ticket-or-a-flight-reservation-for-my-uk-visit-visa-applicati)
- Unless you address the reason(s) for the refusal, success is very unlikely.